# Which significance test do I need to compare variance of run lengths?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

By 'run length' I mean the length of a streak of H or T in a sequence of coin tosses. e.g. suppose the sequence is HH T H TTT HH T; the run lengths are 2,1,1,3,2,1.

I would like to compare the variance of a generated sequence of run lengths with the theoretical variance for the run length, but I don't know what this value is, and even if I did, the distribution of run lengths isn't normal so apparently I shouldn't use the F-test to compare variances because it's sensitive to non-normality.

However, I *do* know what the mean run length should be, so I was thinking of getting the mean from several generated samples and doing a t-test or z-test for the comparison of means. If the mean of the samples is significantly different from the H0 mean, then the variance of the distribution should be significantly different too - is that correct?

Alternatively, could anyone suggest another (presumably non-parametric) test for the variance? Thanks.

Comment: Even if you had normality it wouldn't be an F test; that would be for comparing two sample variances, not comparing one variance to a specified one (which would instead be a chi-squared test).

Comment: 1. Are we taking the coin to be fair, or are we conditioning on the observed counts of heads and tails? 2. It would be worth explaining why you want to test the variance of run-length; there may be better suggestions if we understand the underlying problem you're trying to solve by doing so.

Comment: Thanks for your input. No, the coin isn't necessarily fair; that's actually what I want to test for, but I want to know whether the variance differs from the 'expected' variance and not just do a test to compare the proportion of H or T.

Comment: Why would you look at the variance rather than the mean?

Comment: Because I have reason to believe that the sequences may be more 'choppy' (shorter runs) than they would be if there were no bias. Just looking at the mean wouldn't tell me anything about that.

Comment: If the runs are shorter the mean run length will be lower.

Comment: Yes, sorry, my previous reply was wrong (the mean will be affected if the run lengths are shorter  - that's what I was referring to in my question). You've answered my question and I don't need a test for variance directly because the mean length WILL be different. Thanks.